# C++ Program, convert regular file to hexadecimal and binary

Tags: c++

My HexDump that I have takes a file and outputs the ASCII hex value of that file, and also the binary values of that file. In example, when I run my program on a text file containing "Hello World!", I get
4865 6C6C 6F20 etc. So I know it is converting the direct ascii characters to the correct hex values. But, an example in my program syllabus shows that other bytes should be printed before the text.

This leads me to believe that I am not reading the entire file correctly. I think I may need to use fread() or fopen()? Please help me out. I am a C++ beginner. This is my code that I run on my txt file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

string stringToHexOrByte(char input, bool toByte)
{
    string output;

    if (toByte) {
        bitset<8> temp(input);
        output = temp.to_string();
    }
    else {
        static const char hex_digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        output.reserve(2);
        output.push_back(hex_digits[input >> 4]);
        output.push_back(hex_digits[input & 15]);
    }

    return output;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Create a text string, which is used to output the text file
    string initialInput;
    // char variable in order to read char by char from file
    char myChar;
    //bool value to know if we have the byte parameter called
    bool byteOption;
    // string which will retain the converted char to hex or byte
    string convChar;
    string fileName;
    //Check if we have -b byte Option
    if (argc > 2) {
        byteOption = true;
        fileName = argv[2];
    }
    else {
        byteOption = false;
        fileName = argv[1];
    }
    // Read from the text file
    fstream myFile(fileName, fstream::in);
    // we will use this group variable to separate the chars printed as in the examples
    int group = 1;
    while (myFile >> std::noskipws >> myChar) {

        // if the bynary option is selected we will print all the chars separetely
        if (byteOption) {
            group = 0;
        }

        convChar = stringToHexOrByte(myChar, byteOption);
        cout << convChar;

        // here we use the group to get the output expected
        if (group) {
            group = 0;
        }
        else {
            cout << " ";
            group = 1;
        }

        //clear non-printable chars
        if ((int)myChar < 32) {
            myChar = '.';
        }

        // Append to input string
        initialInput.append(1, myChar);
    }
    // Close the file
    myFile.close();

    //print input
    cout << "  " << initialInput;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no need for casting to `int` to compare its ASCII value, just `if (myChar < 32)` is fine, `char` is a numerical type. You may want to use `unsigned char` to force unsigned so that you don't get meaningless negative values in there. You'll also have to deal with character encoding issues relating to UTF-8.

Comment: What other bytes do your examples have?  Perhaps the file they're dealing with has a UTF [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (the bytes `FE FF` or `FF FE`).  Most text editors won't emit one of those unless you save the file as UTF-16 (and even then, some won't write one unless you explicitly tell them to), so it probably has less to do with how you're reading the file and more to do with how you're writing it.

Comment: @MilesBudnek The example file outputs 0504 06 and then the same thing as my output follows.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a BOM then.  In general, a text file shouldn't have any other bytes before the first character (except maybe a BOM).  Either it's an example of output with extra non-printable characters or there's some other requirement you haven't mentioned.